# Migrating My Web Applications from My Previous Laptop to My New Laptop

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-7, windows-vista, iis-7.5

So I've just purchased a new laptop which has Windows 7 on it; upgrading from my previous laptop with Windows Vista.

I've copied my files from one laptop to the other, have installed Visual Studio 2010 on the new laptop, and enabled IIS (through "Turn Windows Features On or Off").

On a related note all of my web apps were set up as virtual applications under the default website.

I went into Visual Studio and tried to open up one of the virtual applications and starting getting errors finding the application and connecting to the databases.  First, I received an error that the application didn't exist, so I added the virtual application (with the same name as before) to IIS which resolved the issue, but then I started getting issues connecting to the database files (*.mdf in the App_Data folder of each application).

My question is what are the right steps to take to properly set up all of these applications on my new laptop?

Your advice is greatly appreciated,
Shawn

Answer (score 1):

it might be related to the setup of the new laptop, is visual studio and ASP.NET properly installed? Can you create a new web application which access to a local database file and have it running and debug it with no problem?

if all this is fine, send more information about the errors you are getting and we can try to understand what's happening.

Davide.